# 1990's movie about kidnapped android prostitutes

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a scifi movie that I think was released in the mid to late 1990's.  From what I recall, it was about some very high-quality androids that were used as prostitutes/pleasure robots, possibly modeled after famous actresses.  Some of them were kidnapped and the protagonist must try to track them down.

Sorry I don't have more specifics, but I only saw part of it and I am trying to find it so that I can watch the whole thing.

Comment: It's not the movie "Automata" is it? It's a 2014 release that involves a pleasure bot escaping capture.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_2000 ?

Comment: It's not Automata because I saw it originally around 1998/9. And it's not Cherry 2000 either, though that's closer.  But thanks for your guesses!

Comment: That's essentially the plot of the animated video for "Float (My Electric Stargirl)", by Atomic Swindlers.  The video was freely downloadable 10 or 12 years ago, not sure about present day.

Comment: Animated? Or with live actors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for [*Cyberzone*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/6303801773) or *[Droid Gunner](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112906/)*, which seem to be two titles for the same movie:

> 2077, twenty years after an earthquake has sent all the states along the western American seaboard into the ocean. The populace is divided between monied classes living inside domed cities and the poor and mutated in the wastelands outside. In Phoenix City, bounty hunter Jack Ford receives an assignment from a corporation to track down four female pleasure androids that have been stolen from a colony on Jupiter. Jack is reluctantly paired with cybernetic specialist Beth Enright who has never been outside the city before. The two follow a trail that leads through the seedy wasteland underworld to an operation smuggling vice into the morally pure underwater city of New Angeles.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I found to what you might be talking about was a 1999 movie called ["Veronica 2030"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0189184) A 'fully functional' pleasure android is sent back to 1998 & becomes a lingerie model. Her creators travel back to try to rescue her.

Comment: When it comes to story-id questions, we tend to prefer answers that explain what elements of the work match up with the memories in the question.

Comment: @Bryce:
:) Sorry to keep picking at you, but we also like to have such information edited into the answer. I have done so for you.

Comment: My impulse is that this is probably not the answer, as it's about only a single android.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm...the movie this brings to mind for me is actually from 2009, but it definitely bears some similarity to the plot you're describing. Is it possibly a little newer than the late 90s?

The movie I'm thinking of is called "[Surrogates](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0986263/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_29)", and it was basically people living virtual lives and doing all kinds of crazy things that they'd never do in their real bodies...except that the "virtual" entities were actually people who signed up to be someone else's virtual "surrogate" for a paycheck. Prostitution and sexual deviancy were part of the norm.

Comment: I think you're mixing up two movies. The surrogates in Surrogates were mechanical bodies, not people. Unless there were two Surrogates movies released in 2009.

Comment: The other film, about virtual lives with real people, is 2009's "Gamer".